# If a ratio of functions has a limit then the ration of their integrals also has the same limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've faced an exersice that seems quite simple to me, but I'm stucked in thinking of the initial idea.

Let $f, g $ be Riemann-integrable on every $[a;b] \subset [x_o; + \infty) $ and $g >0$ on $[x_o; + \infty) $.

Let also $\int_{x_o}^{\infty} g(x)dx=+\infty$. Let's assume that $\exists lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f}{g}=c$. Then i need to prove that

$\exists lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\int_{x_o}^{x} f(x)dx}{\int_{x_o}^{x} g(x)dx}=c$

Obviously I had a great desire to apply L'Hôpital's rule here, but also it's obvious that it's not good for the case.

Comment: Why do you think L'Hospital is not good for this case?

Comment: because there's no reason for the integrals to be differentiable

Comment: Do you assume $c>0$?

Comment: no, the constant $c$ can be arbitary(and even $+ \infty$ or $-\infty$)

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: Assume $c = 0$. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $x_1 \ge x_0$ such that for every $x\ge x_1$ it follows
$$ |f(x)| < \varepsilon g(x). $$
In particular, we have
$$ \limsup_{x\to\infty} \left| \frac{\int_{x_0}^x f(t)}{\int_{x_0}^x g(t)} \right| 
= \limsup_{x\to\infty} \left| \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) + \int_{x_1}^{x} f(t)}{\int_{x_0}^{x} g(t)} \right | 
\le \limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_1} |f(t)|}{\int_{x_0}^{x} g(t)} + \varepsilon = 0 + \varepsilon. $$
That is, the quotient of the integral converges to zero.

Case 2: Assume $0 < |c| \le \infty$. Adapter the proof of case 1 or cf @zhw.'s answer.

Comment: Okay, I've made the same thing that you did in case 1 for any $c $, $|c|< \infty$ and it worked.

Comment: I don't think that l'Hospital is valid here, but thank's a lot anyway

Comment: You can apply L'Hopital if $f,g$ are both continuous, but that is not given.

Comment: @zhw. You are right

Comment: I just noticed my solution is very much like your $c=0$ solution. If you like, I'll delete my answer and you can extend your $c=0$ idea to a full solution.

Comment: @zhw. Na. I am fine with it. After all I was too lazy to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume $c\in \mathbb R$ and leave the $\pm \infty$ case to you.

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $x_1>x_0$ such that $f(x)/g(x)<c+\epsilon$ for $x>x_1.$ For such $x$ we have

$$\frac{\int_{x_0}^x f}{\int_{x_0}^x g} =\frac{\int_{x_0}^x f+\int_{x_1}^x f}{\int_{x_0}^x g+\int_{x_1}^x g}$$ $$< \frac{\int_{x_0}^x f+\int_{x_1}^x (c+\epsilon)g}{\int_{x_0}^x g+\int_{x_1}^x g} = \frac{\int_{x_0}^x f+(c+\epsilon)\int_{x_1}^x g}{\int_{x_0}^x g+\int_{x_1}^x g}.$$

Now divide both top and bottom by $\int_{x_1}^x g$ and take the $\limsup$ of both sides as $x\to \infty.$ We get

$$ \limsup_{\,x\to \infty} \frac{\int_{x_0}^x f}{\int_{x_0}^x g} \le \frac{0+(c+\epsilon)}{0+1} = c+\epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, the above $\limsup$ is $\le c.$

A similiar proof shows the corresponding $\liminf $ is $\ge c.$ Thus the limit equals $c$ as desired.